# Error updating graph invalid component prop figure

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Just creating a simple Graph, from an excel file, it loads correctly but at the moment of updating the graph dash gives back this error:

```
Failed component prop type: Invalid component prop figure key props supplied to Graph.

Bad object: {

“props”: {

“id”: “average_country”,

“figure”: {

“data”: [

{
“x”: [
“DE”,
“ES”,
“FR”,
“IT”,
“UK”
],

“y”: [
[
2365.56,
4528.33875,
4851.085,
4325.14,
2107.921428571429
]
],

“type”: “bar”
}
],

“layout”: {

“title”: “Hyperzone”
}
}
},

“type”: “Graph”,

“namespace”: “dash_core_components”
}

Valid keys: [
“data”,
“layout”,
“frames”
]
```

I’m just using a pivot table to create the mean of data of some countries, here’s my code, the pivot table is correct and outputs a valid result with the values I want, just when I try to update the graph with the callback function it returns an Error message.

```
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

HP= pd.read_excel(r’C:\Users\salinejs\HP.xlsx’)
Columns = [‘Station’, ‘Week’, ‘Owner’, ‘Cost’,‘Country’]
HP_filtered = HP[Columns]

avaliable_weeks= HP_filtered[‘Week’].unique()

external_stylesheets = [‘https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css’]

app = dash.Dash(name, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
html.Div([
html.Div([

    html.Div([
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id= 'Week_filter',
            options = [{'label':j, 'value':j}for j in avaliable_weeks],
            value= 'Week 42'
        ),

    ],
    style= {'float':'left', 'display':'inline-block'}
    ),



    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(
            id='average_country',
        )
        ],
    )
    ]
),
],

)

@app.callback(
Output(‘average_country’, ‘figure’),
[Input(‘Week_filter’,‘value’)]
)

def update_value(week):

HP_filtered_week = HP_filtered[ HP_filtered['Week'] == week ]

pv = pd.pivot_table(HP_filtered_week, values='Cost', columns='Country', index='Week')

print(pv)
print(pv.columns)

return dcc.Graph(
    id='average_country',
    figure={
        'data': [{'x': pv.columns , 'y' : pv.values,'type': 'bar'
                  }],

        'layout':{
            'title': 'Cost',

        }


    })

if name == ‘main’:
app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit late - you probably sorted this by now, but I just had the same error and an answer here would have saved me time.

It's because you are sending the callback output to figure but the function is returning the entire dcc.Graph() instead of just the figure.

change

```
return dcc.Graph(
    id='average_country',
    figure={
        'data': [{'x': pv.columns , 'y' : pv.values,'type': 'bar'
                  }],

        'layout':{
            'title': 'Cost',

        }


    })
```

to

```
return {'data': [{'x': pv.columns , 'y' : pv.values,'type': 'bar'
                  }],

        'layout':{
            'title': 'Cost',},}
```